# Html does not import css file

Tags: html, css, django

Silly question but i can't figure it out and it's too much. In a django project, in the same directory i have base_template.html and base_style.css. In a child folder i have search.html.

```
base_template.html
base_style.css
folder---- 
          search.html
```

Search.html extends base_template.html like so

```
{% extends "base_template.html" %}
```

Inside **base_template.html** i import **base_style.css**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %} Base template {% endblock %}</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="awesome_font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <style>
    {% block Additional_Styles %}
    {% endblock %}
    </style>
```

And there's no way it works. 
**Already tried:

```
./base_style.css
 /base_style.css
 base_style.css"/**
```

If i replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base_style.css">
```

with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```

It works, the css loads. I must mention that i just downloaded the css from the link **and made no modifications.**

Why doesnt the import work?

**EDIT**

**settings.py**:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],

 ....
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
```

So the base_template is in MainDjangoApp\templates

Comment: Please try to avoid the underscore and use the midscore !

Comment: Maybe you have to find out what the real docroot path is and then navigate to your template file.

Answer (score 2):

You should pu your static files (.css, .js) in a static folder inside your app:

```
app
   static
       app 
          css
              base_style.css
```

adn in your template you should use

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/css/base_style.css' %}">
```

You should definitely read [Writing your first Django app, part 6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial06/#writing-your-first-django-app-part-6) and [Managing static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) on the djangoproject site.

Comment: it still doesnt work. Can it be something from settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would have been to change the folder of base_style.css as in the docs, however i added this to settings.py and i got it working. My app is not that complex so i won't get tangled in files.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
]
```